# Searching and adding to array list

Tags: java, arraylist

what i'm trying to do with the method below is look for a specific student in an array list that where the name and unique number(HUN) match the key and keyInt respectively. Once that student is found it should add to the local array list returnStudent and return it. However the line `returnStudent.add(student(i));` is giving me an error and i can't figure out how to fix it,i need it to add the specific student to the local array list.

```
public ArrayList<Student1> searchByKey(String key, int keyInt)
{
    ArrayList<Student1> returnStudent = new ArrayList<Student1>();
    Student1 student = new Student1(key);
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= students.size())
    {
        if(student.getName().equals(key) && student.getHUN() == keyInt)
        {
            return Student.add(student(i));
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
    return returnStudent;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `i < students.size()`

Comment: `is giving me an error` .. what is that error ?

Comment: students and student are different ?

Comment: What is `students` and where is it declared?

Comment: students is the array list i'm searching and student is the variable for the object Student1.

Comment: what is `student` used for and what is `students` used for?

Comment: @MoProHD you might want to consider naming your variables better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
returnStudent.add(student(i));
```

to

```
returnStudent.add(student); // student is the element
```

to add to a specific index, use -

```
returnStudent.add(i, student); // i is the index to add element at
```

***Note*** - since you have initialized `i=0` you shall iterate through `i < students.size()` or you might end up accessing `get(i)` on the list for the value that doesn't exist (base indexed to 0).

---

The other way to do what you are trying to achieve is using Java8 as -

```
ArrayList<Student1> students = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Student1> searchByKey(String key, int keyInt) {
    ArrayList<Student1> returnStudent = new ArrayList<>();
    Student1 student = new Student1(key);
    students.forEach(element -> {
        if (element.getName().equals(key) && element.getHUN() == keyInt) {
            returnStudent.add(element);
        }
    });
    return returnStudent;
}
```

Comment: would this add the specific student that i'm looking for to returnStudent? the reason i added 'i' is because student 'i' is the one im looking for

Answer (score 0):

You loop through `students`. But add `student(i)`. Note the s at the end. Change the add to `students(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `students` is an `ArrayList` with prepopulated data, you can do the following.

```
public ArrayList<Student1> searchByKey(String key, int keyInt) {
    ArrayList<Student1> returnStudent = new ArrayList<Student1>();

    for(Student1 student1 : students) {
        if(student1.getName().equals(key) && student1.getHUN() == keyInt) {
            returnStudent.add(student1);
        }
    }

    return returnStudent;
}
```

I have changed the while loop to foreach loop to make it look simpler and easily understandable.